# undefined reference to operator<<

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

есть класс с перегруженным оператором <<

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
private:
   //...

public:
    //...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Array<T> &obj);
};
```

Реализация перегрузки такая(реализация, как и положено, в хедере):

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Array<T> &obj)
{
    //..

    return os;
}
```

В мейне пишу следующий код:

```
cout << "arr: " << arr << endl;
```

В результате выдает ошибку:

> ошибка: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Array const&)'

В чем проблема? Перечитал уже все и русско и англо язычные форму, ни одни советы не помогают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявите друга (он же у вас шаблонный) так:

```
template<typename U>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Array<U> &obj);
```

Comment: Таже самая ошибка. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Вот, смотрите...http://ideone.com/cbPduc

Comment: Черт, ничего не понимаю... сделал, как вы советовали и скопировал весь код прямо в main.cpp - работает, а в хенедере вообще никак.